# Compute all with one button

Tags: android

I’m making an app that can compute all I needed with just 1 click of a button, but its forced closing when I'm pushing the “calculate” button, can anyone help me with what I did wrong?

```
    previous = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    present = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

    Button calculate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calculate);

    consumption = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    basic = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    mmp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    stp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    before = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
    penalty = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView6);
    after = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView7);

    calculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            makeCalculations();
        }
    });
}
private void makeCalculations() {

    double n1 = Double.valueOf(previous.getText().toString());
    double n2 = Double.valueOf(present.getText().toString());
    double n3 = Double.valueOf(consumption.getText().toString());
    double n4 = Double.valueOf(stp.getText().toString());
    double n5 = Double.valueOf(mmp.getText().toString());
    double n6 = Double.valueOf(penalty.getText().toString());
    double n7 = Double.valueOf(before.getText().toString());
    double n8 = Double.valueOf(basic.getText().toString());



    consumption.setText("Your Consumption is: " + (n1 + n2));
    basic.setText("Your Consumption is: " + (n3 * 280.00));
    mmp.setText("Meter Maintenance Fee: " + 10.00);
    stp.setText("Septage Fee: " + (n3 * 0.068) );
    before.setText("On/Before Due Date: " + (n3 + n4 + n5));
    penalty.setText("Penalty: " + (n3 / 10.00));
    after.setText("After Due Date: " + (n6 + n7));

}

}
```

Comment: can you post your error log ?

Comment: E/test: Exception
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""
                      at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
                      at java.lang.StringToReal.parseDouble(StringToReal.java:248)
                      at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:295)

Comment: at java.lang.Double.valueOf(Double.java:332)
                      at tutorialspoint.example.com.myapplication.MainActivity.makeCalculations(MainActivity.java:55)
                      at tutorialspoint.example.com.myapplication.MainActivity.access$000(MainActivity.java:10)
                      at tutorialspoint.example.com.myapplication.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:47)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4293)

Comment: at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17535)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)

Comment: at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)

Comment: Please use the "edit" button at the bottom of your post to put the stacktrace in a code block so it's readable and remove the comments

Comment: the log says you have invalid input to convert to Double, you can not convert empty String to a double value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no validation. You should at least check that the string is not empty, but also maybe use a try catch in case a number is not entered. Then you could set the error text on the editText to explain that an invalid number was entered.

So you could do something like this for each double:

```
boolean answerOk = true;

double n1;
if (!previous.getText().toString().equals("") {
    try {
        n1 = Double.valueOf(previous.getText().toString());
    } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
        answerOk = false;
        previous.setError("Invalid number");
    }
} else {
    answerOk = false;
    previous.setError("Field is empty");
}
```

Only run the code at the bottom after all the double's are ok.

```
if (answerOk) {
    // Do the other stuff here
}
```

Comment: i will try your answer, tnx for the reply...